# How to git ls-remote tags in a specific branch

Tags: git, ls-remote, git-ls-remote

Before cloning a repository, I want to list all the tags in the master branch to filter and finally retrieve a subset of required commits without transferring any additional data.

Is it possible to use `git ls-remote` to list all tags in a particular branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git ls-remote` can list branches, tags or heads (branches+tags); it can list all or filter by name but it cannot filter by commit graph because it cannot access commits in the remote repository.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it matches with what I figured out online so long. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

```
git tag --list --merged <branchName>
```

would do the job **on a repo you already have locally**. Could it help your case?

I guess not unless you somehow have access to the remote machine itself.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help. As stated in the answer, I need it _before cloning a repository_.